# tengo un problema con arduino

Tags: c++, arduino

Tengo un problema, a la hora de cambiar el color del semaforo de verde a rojo quiero el el semaforo de peatones parpadee como lo hacen los de la calle, la cosa es que he probado a hacerlo con for, con un bucle, y no funciona, al final me he resignado a probar ordenandole que se apague y se encienda, pero ni aun asi va, lo que pasa esque cuando pulsas el boton, empieza bien pero el led solo hace el parpadeo 1 vez y sigue el codigo, lo que quiero es que haga 5 veces el parpadeo, no 1, si me pudiesen ayudar

```
//Programa receptor


//Directrices
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>   // Incluimos la librería  SoftwareSerial  
SoftwareSerial BT(0,1);    // Definimos los pines RX y TX del Arduino conectados al Bluetooth

const int LuzRoja=13; //Declaras la variable del Led Rojo al pin 13 del arduino
const int LuzVerde=12; //Declaras la variable del Led Verde al pin 12 del arduino
int PulsadorVerde=11; //Declaras la variable del Pulsador Rojo al pin 11 del arduino
int PulsadorRojo=10; //Declaras la variable del Pulsador Rojo al pin 11 del arduino
const int LuzRojaPeaton=9; //Declaras la variable del Led Rojo de los peatones al pin 9 del arduino
const int LuzVerdePeaton=8; //Declaras la variable del Led Verde de los peatones al pin 9 del arduino
char DatoBT;


//setup
void setup()
{
 Serial.begin(9600); //Iniciamos el Monitor serie para establecer la comunicacion BT
  while (!Serial) {} //Hasta que no establezca conexion con el modulo BT no sigue el programa
 pinMode(LuzRoja,OUTPUT);
 pinMode(LuzVerde,OUTPUT);
 pinMode(PulsadorRojo,INPUT); //Configuras el pulsador rojo como entrada
 pinMode(PulsadorVerde,INPUT); //Configuras el pulsador Verde como entrada
 pinMode(LuzRojaPeaton, OUTPUT);
 pinMode(LuzVerdePeaton, OUTPUT);
 digitalWrite(LuzRoja,HIGH); //apagas los pilotos del semaforo
 digitalWrite(LuzVerde,LOW); //apagas los pilotos del semaforo
 digitalWrite(LuzRojaPeaton,LOW); //apagas los pilotos del semaforo
 digitalWrite(LuzVerdePeaton,HIGH); //apagas los pilotos del semaforo
}

//Bucle principal

void loop()
{
    DatoBT = Serial.read(); //Asignas el dato que llegue del BT a la variable DatoBT
    PulsadorRojo=digitalRead(10); //Lees el estado del pulsador Rojo y lo almacenas en su variable
    PulsadorVerde=digitalRead(11); //Lees el estado del pulsador Verde y lo almacenas en su variable
    
  if (PulsadorRojo == HIGH && PulsadorVerde == LOW) //Si rojo esta pulsado y verde no, hace lo que hay dentro de la funcion  
    {
        delay(5000); //Temporiza 5 Segundos
        digitalWrite(LuzVerde, LOW); //Apaga el piloto verde
        digitalWrite(LuzRojaPeaton, LOW);
        delay(1000);
        digitalWrite(LuzRoja, HIGH); //Enciende el piloto rojo
        digitalWrite(LuzVerdePeaton, HIGH);
    }
   if (PulsadorVerde == HIGH && PulsadorRojo == LOW) //Si Verde esta pulsado y rojo no, hace lo que hay dentro de la funcion  
    {
        delay(4000); //Temporiza 4 Segundos
        digitalWrite(LuzVerdePeaton, LOW);
        digitalWrite(LuzVerdePeaton, HIGH);
        delay(500);
        digitalWrite(LuzVerdePeaton, LOW);
        digitalWrite(LuzVerdePeaton, HIGH);
        delay(500);
        digitalWrite(LuzVerdePeaton, LOW);
        digitalWrite(LuzVerdePeaton, HIGH);
        delay(500);
        digitalWrite(LuzVerdePeaton, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(LuzVerdePeaton, LOW);
        delay(500);
        digitalWrite(LuzVerdePeaton, LOW);
        digitalWrite(LuzVerdePeaton, HIGH);
        delay(500);
        digitalWrite(LuzVerdePeaton, LOW);
        digitalWrite(LuzRojaPeaton, HIGH);
        delay(1500);
        digitalWrite(LuzRoja, LOW); //Apaga el piloto rojo
        digitalWrite(LuzVerde, HIGH); //Enciende el piloto Verde
    }

    switch (DatoBT) //le preguntas a la variable que dato ha recibido 
    { 
        case 'R': //Si ha recibido R hace lo que hay dentro de su funcion
        delay(4000); //Temporiza 4 Segundos
        digitalWrite(LuzVerdePeaton, LOW);
        digitalWrite(LuzVerdePeaton, HIGH);
        delay(500);
        digitalWrite(LuzVerdePeaton, LOW);
        digitalWrite(LuzVerdePeaton, HIGH);
        delay(500);
        digitalWrite(LuzVerdePeaton, LOW);
        digitalWrite(LuzVerdePeaton, HIGH);
        delay(500);
        digitalWrite(LuzVerdePeaton, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(LuzVerdePeaton, LOW);
        delay(500);
        digitalWrite(LuzVerdePeaton, LOW);
        digitalWrite(LuzVerdePeaton, HIGH);
        delay(500);
        digitalWrite(LuzVerdePeaton, LOW);
        digitalWrite(LuzRojaPeaton, HIGH);
        delay(1500);
        digitalWrite(LuzRoja, LOW); //Apaga el piloto rojo
        digitalWrite(LuzVerde, HIGH); //Enciende el piloto Verde
          Serial.end(); //Terminas la comunicacion BT para reiniciar el dato a recibir
          Serial.begin(9600); //Iniciamos el Monitor serie para establecer la comunicacion BT
          break; //Rompe las ordenes
        case 'V': //Si ha recibido V hace lo que hay dentro de su funcion
          delay(4500); //Temporiza 5 Segundos
          digitalWrite(LuzRojaPeaton, HIGH);
          delay(1000);
          digitalWrite(LuzRoja, LOW); //Apaga el piloto rojo
          digitalWrite(LuzVerde, HIGH); //Enciende el piloto Verde
          Serial.end(); //Terminas la comunicacion BT para reiniciar el dato a recibir
          Serial.begin(9600); //Iniciamos el Monitor serie para establecer la comunicacion BT
          break; //Rompe las ordenes
    }
}
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y pon en el título el problema _específico_ que estás teniendo, en formato resumido, para atraer más usuarios a la pregunta. Un título incompleto o no descriptivo "espanta" a quienes no quieren dar un vistazo a la pregunta completa. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Mira lo que estás haciendo: `digitalWrite(LuzVerdePeaton, LOW);digitalWrite(LuzVerdePeaton, HIGH);delay(500);` en español esto es: "apaga, enciende, espera 500 milisegundos". Si la apagas y acto seguido la enciendes sin esperar el medio segundo en medio, no vas a verlo. No es que no te haga caso, es que te hace caso tan rápido que no lo ves... puede que el arduino sea pequeñito, pero créeme que le sobra velocidad para ejecutar líneas de código (mientras no hagas cálculos matemáticos complejos claro)

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow. Te invito a hacer el [tour] y te comento que el título de la pregunta está fatal. Todas las preguntas aquí podrían titularse "tengo un problema con XXX" y entonces la búsqueda y otras operaciones serían imposibles. Te invito a mejorarlo. Encontrarás más información en [ask].

Comment: El `delay` tiene que ir entre el `LOW` y el `HIGH`....NO al final del `LOW` como lo tienes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba a revisar las esperas por si no te funciona bien el parpadeo. Por ejemplo:

```
delay(4000); //Temporiza 4 Segundos

digitalWrite(LuzVerdePeaton, LOW);
digitalWrite(LuzVerdePeaton, HIGH);
delay(500);
// aqui está HIGH por 500ms
digitalWrite(LuzVerdePeaton, LOW);
// Low pero inmediatamente después high. Seguramente no lo puedas percibir con el ojo
digitalWrite(LuzVerdePeaton, HIGH);
delay(500);
// otros 500 ms high
```

En resumen, puede que sólo veas el led encendido.

Prueba a hacer un parpadeo de 500ms encendido, 500ms apagado

```
digitalWrite(LuzVerdePeaton, LOW);
delay(500);
digitalWrite(LuzVerdePeaton, HIGH);
delay(500);
digitalWrite(LuzVerdePeaton, LOW);
```